# Bootstrap drop down inside fixed height div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a bootstrap drop down menu inside a fixed height div with scrollable content `(overflow-y: scroll;)`. My problem is that when the menu gets longer heights, it hides inside its parent div as it has vertical scrollbar. I want to display it full size (above its parent). z-index not working with this.

```css
.highlights-box {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: camberia;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.highlights-box h1 {
  font-family: camberia;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.unesco {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.city-heading {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.monuments {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.monuments li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.highlights-box .dropdown-menu {
  top: 66%;
  left: 100px;
  z-index:9999;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 0px;
}

.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 highlights-box">
  <h1>Tour Highlights</h1>
  <div class="unesco" style="border-bottom:none; padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:5px;">U = UNESCO World Heritage Site</div>
  <div class="unesco" style="border-top:none; padding-bottom:8px">E = Unique Experience</div>
  <div class="monuments" id="monuments">
    <div class="city-heading">
      <a id="Delhi"></a>
      <div class="city-heading dropdown dropdown-toggle"><span onclick="scrollDiv('Delhi',jQuery(this))">Delhi</span><span class="caret"></span>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li onclick="scrollDiv('Varanasi',jQuery(this))"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Varanasi</a></li>
          <li onclick="scrollDiv('Agra',jQuery(this))"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Agra</a></li>
          <li onclick="scrollDiv('Abhaneri (Enroute)',jQuery(this))"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Abhaneri (Enroute)</a></li>
          <li onclick="scrollDiv('Ranthambore',jQuery(this))"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Ranthambore</a></li>
          <li onclick="scrollDiv('Jaipur',jQuery(this))"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Jaipur</a></li>
          <li onclick="scrollDiv('Ranakpur',jQuery(this))"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Ranakpur</a></li>
          <li onclick="scrollDiv('Udaipur',jQuery(this))"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Udaipur</a></li>
          <li onclick="scrollDiv('Mumbai',jQuery(this))"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Mumbai</a></li>
          <li onclick="scrollDiv('Aurangabad',jQuery(this))"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Aurangabad</a></li>
          <li onclick="scrollDiv('Cochin',jQuery(this))"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Cochin</a></li>
          <li onclick="scrollDiv('Backwaters',jQuery(this))"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Backwaters</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <li>Qutab Minar - U</li>
    <li>Guided walk through ancient spice bazaar in Chandni Chowk - E</li>
    <li>Red Fort - U</li>
    <li>Rickshaw Ride in Old Delhi's Crowded Bazaar - E</li>
    <li>India Gate</li>
    <li>National Museum</li>
    <li>Humayun's Tomb - U</li>
    <li>Bangla Sahib Gurudwara - E</li>
    <li>Jama Masjid</li>

    <div class="city-heading">
      <a id="Varanasi"></a>Varanasi</div>
    <li>Sunset Arti prayer ceremony on the holy river - E</li>
    <li>Sunrise and Sunset boat cruises on the holy river - E</li>
    <li>Sarnath Archaelogical Museum*</li>

    <div class="city-heading">
      <a id="Agra"></a>Agra</div>
    <li>Agra Fort - U</li>
    <li>Taj Mahal (Both sunrise and sunset visits) - U</li>

    <div class="city-heading">
      <a id="Abhaneri (Enroute)"></a>Abhaneri (Enroute)</div>
    <li>Rajasthani Village Walk - E</li>
    <li>Chand Baori Stepwell</li>

    <div class="city-heading">
      <a id="Ranthambore"></a>Ranthambore</div>
    <li>Wildlife Safaris</li>
    <li>Ranthambore Fort</li>

    <div class="city-heading">
      <a id="Jaipur"></a>Jaipur</div>
    <li>Amber Fort and Palace - U</li>
    <li>Jantar Mantar - U</li>
    <li>City Palace</li>
    <li>Hawa Mahal (Palace of the Winds)</li>
    <li>Monkey Temple - E</li>
    <li>Elephant Ride to Amer Fort - E</li>
    <li>Camelback (or Camel cart) safari at Samode - E</li>
    <li>Rajasthani Lunch at Samode Palace</li>

    <div class="city-heading">
      <a id="Ranakpur"></a>Ranakpur</div>
    <li>15th Century Jain Temple</li>
    <li>Purebred Marwari Horse Ride - E</li>

    <div class="city-heading">
      <a id="Udaipur"></a>Udaipur</div>
    <li>City Palace</li>
    <li>Crystal Gallery</li>
    <li>Monsoon Palace Excursion - E</li>
    <li>Boat Cruise on Lake Pichola</li>
    <li>Three Wheeler (Tuk Tuk) ride through the streets of Udaipur - E</li>

    <div class="city-heading">
      <a id="Mumbai"></a>Mumbai</div>
    <li>The Gateway Of India</li>
    <li>Prince of Wales Museum</li>
    <li>The Victoria Terminus - U</li>
    <li>Drive on the Queen's Necklace (Marine Drive)</li>
    <li>Historic Flora Fountain and Fort area exploration</li>
    <li>Mumbai's Launderers - Old Traditional Dhobi Ghats - E</li>

    <div class="city-heading">
      <a id="Aurangabad"></a>Aurangabad</div>
    <li>Ajanta Caves - U</li>
    <li>Ellora Caves - U</li>

    <div class="city-heading">
      <a id="Cochin"></a>Cochin</div>
    <li>Cherai Island - E</li>
    <li>15th Century Synangogue</li>
    <li>St. Francis Church</li>
    <li>Chinese Fishing Nets</li>
    <li>Fort Kochi historic architecture</li>
    <li>Kathakali Dance Performance</li>
    <li>Dinner and cooking lesson with a famous Keralan chef - E</li>

    <div class="city-heading">
      <a id="Backwaters"></a>Backwaters</div>
    <li>Cruise through the idyllic backwaters - E</li>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6xtjr8w/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because when `position:absolute` elements are inside parents with both `position:relative` and `overflow:hidden or scroll`, they will be cropped by their parent.

The solution is to set these styles separately on two parent levels: set `position: relative` to direct parent of the absolute element, but set the `overflow` (scroll or hidden) on a grand-parent element! as in following pattern:

```
<div class="grand-parent">  => position: relative;  
  <div class="parent">      => overflow: hidden; (or scroll;)  
    <div class="child">     => position: absolute; 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your case, we can use existing elements to do so.

- add `position:relative` to `.highlights-box` div which acts as our grand-parent.
- the `overflow-y: scroll` is set on `.monuments` div. this acts as mid-parent.
- Then we override `position:relative` of `.dropdown` by modifying `.city-heading` class such that `.city-heading` be normal (static) position element.

The style changes are as following:

```
.highlights-box {
  ...
  position: relative; /* !!EDIT!! ensure pos:relative of grand-parent */
}

.city-heading {
  ...
  position: static; /* override position:relative of .dropdown */
}

.highlights-box .dropdown-menu {
  top: 53%; /* better position than 66% */
  ...
}
```

and here is the [updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/e6xtjr8w/3/)